# Using Javascript IF function to create Google Tag Manager Variable

Tags: if-statement, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to create a custom variable in Google Tag Manager. I need it to show a 0 value when...

A customer purchases using a discount code which contains the words 'Gift Voucher'
**AND**
It generates negative revenue.

Else it should just appear standard revenue (there are times when negative revenue is needed, hence why it should only appear as 0 when a gift voucher is used)

Ive tried the following

```
function () { if ({{Discount Code Used}} = str.includes("Gift Voucher") && {{Revenue}}<0 ) {return 0; } else { return {{Revenue}}; }}
```

But this is returning a undefined value

Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first half of your `if` condition is a bit off:

```js
{{Discount Code Used}} = str.includes('Gift Voucher')
```

The right way to use the `.includes()` method of a string is like this:

```js
{{Discount Code Used}}.includes('Gift Voucher')
```

I would recommend using [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) instead of [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), since it is supported by more browsers.

```js
{{Discount Code Used}}.indexOf('Gift Voucher') !== -1
```

If it is still returning `undefined`, double check that `Discount Code Used` and `Revenue` are set to the correct values.

Comment: That's great, it's fixed my undefined issue. However the rule isn't quite working, everything seems to be falling under the 'else' result. Ive done some testing, and the <0 section works fine. So i've isolated it to that first section again with the discount code (using indexof as you mentioned). I have realised that the {{Discount Code Used}} variable does return an array, could this be the issue? it would look something like ['Gift Voucher ABCDE123456789']

Comment: Ah, yes, the array would confuse `.indexOf()`.  I think the best option option is you could convert the array to a string using [`.join(',')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), like this: `{{Discount Code Used}}.join(',').indexOf...`.